# Function Calling with CLION C++

Tags: c++

I've been trying to learn C++ and I chose CLION as my main IDE. I was trying to learn about function calls and made this little script:

```
int main(){

    //This is a comment

    /*
        This is a multilined Comment
        std::cout << is like a print() statement in java
        std::cout << sometihng << std::endl; is something like println()
        Also don't nest comments... Its gonna cause errors
    */

    std::cout << "Hello World!: " << std::endl;

    println("My name is: ");
    print("Physics")
    print("Prodigy")

}

void print(const char *string){
    std::cout << string;
}


void println(const char *string){
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}
```

(I also wrote all the void functions myself these were not IDE generated at first)

As I was trying to build this project, I got a compile error : 'print' was not declared in this scope did you mean 'printf'. I've gotten CLION to generate these automatic suggested functions itself and deleted the generated code. I tested that with println causing my original println to work, but my print function still gives me a compile error. Is this an IDE issue? Or is C++ very finicky

Comment: Move your `print` and `println` functions to above `main`.

Comment: C++ reads most things (the contents of `class`s are a notable exception) top-to bottom. Declare or define the functions before you use them. Me, I'd move `main` to the end and watch the problem go away.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll keep this is mind!

Answer (score 1):

In C/C++ you must declare a variable/function before using it, otherwise the compiler will give an error. You can't do something like

```
a = 10;  // Use variable
int a;   // ERROR: declare the variable after use
```

Same thing applies to function. The compiler must have access to function definition or at least function prototype before you call the function.

So in your case, you can either declare function prototype before `main` function or move the entire function definition before `main` function as suggested by others in the comment.

```cpp
// Function prototype
void print(const char *string);
void println(const char *string);

int main()
{
    ...
    print(...);
    println(...);
}

void print(const char *string){
    std::cout << string;
}

void println(const char *string){
    std::cout << string << std::endl;
}
```

Usually function prototypes are declared in header files and those headers are included in the source file. This way compiler will have access to function prototype before the function is used in the source file.